# Website on Macs is ssl certified (Chrome)? Stylesheet not working

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

HI i'm accessing http://videobrochurecanada.ca/ on macs and it is prompting an ssl certificate error and then not running the stylesheet. Works fine on PCs Chrome.

Can someone help fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificate that is returned when accessing `videobrochurecanada.ca` has the wrong name. It's actually issued to `newserver.dolcemag.com`.

See the [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=videobrochurecanada.ca&hideResults=on) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/rbt2I).)

Comment: You are right but my other websites show newserver.dolcemag.com as well and they work. How can I possibly go about fixing this one?

Comment: Fix it server side. You've got this line in your html: `<link rel='stylesheet' id='pexeto-fullpage-css-css'  href='https://videobrochurecanada.ca/wp-content/themes/thestory/css/fullpage.css?ver=1.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />` and this can't work over https if the certificate is wrong. Either fix the certificate or move to plain http.